# Parameters in image link not echoing

Tags: php

```
echo '<a href="LP_Teacher_Response_G4.php Lesson_id=$Lesson_id&user_id=$user_id&Lesson_Class_id=$Lesson_Class_id&class_id=$class_id">
    <img height="62" src="../Images/Lock.png" width="76" /></a>';
```

Hi,

I am not sure why my parameters do not show in the link, instead it outputs the code statement, played around with it but not sure what needs to be done.

Comment: File extension needs to be `.php` with an opening tag `<?php`

Comment: Try `LP_Teacher_Response_G4.php?Lesson_id='.$Lesson_id.'&user_id='.$user_id.'`

Comment: See this question to understand your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
echo "<a href=\"LP_Teacher_Response_G4.php?Lesson_id=$Lesson_id&user_id=$user_id&Lesson_Class_id=$Lesson_Class_id&class_id=$class_id\"><img height=\"62\" src=\"../Images/Lock.png\" width=\"76\" /></a>";
```

Comment: this gave me a http 500 error

Comment: You should add your base URL first and add a query string after that like `http://example.com?LP_Teacher..` and so on. Try this way.